# SQL Error :Full-text predicates cannot appear in an aggregate expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute the following query and getting a error. 
but when i tried to use commented lines its work. but not working with contains function.

```
select
2015-min(c.Year)+1  as experiance 
, sum (case when not c.JudgementID_FK is null then 1 else 0 end ) as reported_Judgements
, sum( case 
 when 
 (
 Contains( c.Result , 'ACCEPT')
 or 
Contains( c.Result , 'ALLOW' )
or 
contains (c.Result , 'Grant')
    -- (
    -- c.Result = 'Accepted' or c.Result = 'Allowed' 
    -- or c.Result='allowed' or c.Result='accepted'
    -- or c.Result ='bail allowed(accepted)'
    -- or c.Result = 'admitted'
    -- or c.Result = 'Accepted.'
    -- or c.Result = 'accepted.'
    -- ) 
    -- and 
 --cl.LawyerOf = 'Petitioner' 
 )
  then 1 else 0  end) as win_cases

 , sum (case when c.JudgementID_FK is null then 1 else 1 end ) as total_Cases
from CaseTLS c, CaseLawyer cl , Lawyer l 
Where 

 c.CaseId = cl.CaseId
and cl.ComputerCode = l.ComputerCode

group by l.computercode
order by l.computercode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) "*CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause*" and you are trying to use it in the `SELECT` clause.

Try using PATINDEX instead:

```
select
2015-min(c.Year)+1  as experiance 
, sum (case when not c.JudgementID_FK is null then 1 else 0 end ) as reported_Judgements
, sum( case 
 when 
 (
 PATINDEX( '%ACCEPT%', UPPER(c.Result)) > 0
 or 
 PATINDEX( '%ALLOW%',  UPPER(c.Result)) > 0
 or 
 PATINDEX( '%GRANT%',  UPPER(c.Result)) > 0
 )
  then 1 else 0  end) as win_cases

 , sum (case when c.JudgementID_FK is null then 1 else 1 end ) as total_Cases
from CaseTLS c, CaseLawyer cl , Lawyer l 
Where 

 c.CaseId = cl.CaseId
and cl.ComputerCode = l.ComputerCode

group by l.computercode
order by l.computercode
```

Comment: i also want to ignore the case of c.result is it works ?

Comment: user the `UPPER` function. Answer edited to include it.